# Exporting info from a text file using batch

Tags: batch, script, extract

I am trying to get the path for the OU my laptop is currently in.
Here is what I have

```
gpresult /r /scope computer >> c:\temp\ou.txt

FIND "CN=" "C:\Temp\ou.txt" > C:\Temp\ou1.txt
```

The output is CN=My-PC,OU=Computers,OU=Information Technology,OU=XXXXXXX,OU=Corporate,DC=XXXXXXXX,DC=com

What I need to do is get the CN=MY-PC and extract the CN=
The names will be different every time, so I need from the first , back to the beginning of the line

I havent found anything that gets me close.

Does anyone have any idea how to get the desired output?

Edited to answer Ricardo
Desired output is My-pc stored as a variable %My-pc%

Comment: Can you show what the output you want should look like, I got a bit confused in " so I need from the first , back to the beginning of the line"

Comment: CMD doesn't have many options for splitting strings - take a look at `FOR /F` loops to split out tokens like https://stackoverflow.com/a/40784439/7411885. If you can use powershell, then `$MyPC = (Get-Content c:\temp\ou.txt | Select-String 'CN=(.*?),').Matches.Groups[1].Value` is pretty simple.

Comment: Can you explain why you're grabbing computer name from gpresult rather than just using `hostname`? There are some better ways even if you need to look up with AD/ldap. `gpresult` can also dump to xml or html if you want better data formatting

Comment: As part of as data migration script for my company, I want to grab the ou path and then remove the pc name and have the new pc name put  in and move the object. If I do it manually, it works. I am trying to get the info so it does it without help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Use a direct filter in a `for` loop filtering the line where it's easier to get the CN

```bat
for /f tokens^=6 %%i in ('gpresult /r /scope computer ^| findstr /e Mode')do echo\%%i
:: Or...
for /f tokens^=6 %%i in ('gpresult /v ^| findstr /e Mode')do echo\%%i
```

---

**Additional resources:**

- [`FindSTR /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html)
- [`For /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)
- [`For /F /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)

  - [`For /F commands`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)
- [Commands Redirection](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php)

  - `|`, `<`, `>`, `2>`, etc.
- [How does the Windows Command Interpreter [`cmd.exe`] Parse Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4094699/6819406)

Comment: 1 last think lo-ol What is the variable called so I can apply it to other parts of the script?

Comment: replace: `...)do echo\%%i` to `...)do set "_my_variable=%%~i"` and use `%_my_variable%`...

Comment: `echo` just `echo`, to define use **[`set "name=value"`](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html)**